# Elasticsearch integration with mongoDB on windows7

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

When I am running

```
    curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_river/test/_meta' -d '{
    "type": "mongodb",
    "mongodb": {
        "db": "test",
        "collection": "es_test"
    },
    "index": {
        "name": "mongoindex",
        "type": "es_test"
    }
}'
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
 {"error":"MapperParsingException[Failed to parse]; nested:JsonParseException[Unexpected character ('m' (code 109)): expected a valid value (number,String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source:[B@61f133ea; line:1, column:8]]; ","status":400}
```

I've made research myself and found this one [elasticsearch users](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Ultra-slow-indexing-td3672298.html) and [MongoDB River Plugin for ElasticSearch](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb)...tried to implement as showed but however have same error....
 If anyone had experience in working with ES in Windows7 environment,
can you please point out what I am doing wrong? I am completely new to
ElasticSearch and will appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me.  Perhaps you had a bogus character in your shell while you were typing?  Try putting it in a file and running it with the shell.

Comment: do I need to use replSet in mongodb?

Comment: Not sure, but that wouldn't make a difference in getting the river configured correctly.

Comment: Mongo DB needs to be set up with an oplog for it to be used with the river component.  An oplog is normally used in a replica set in MongoDB.  For testing purposes you can enable the oplog for a single node MongoDB to get it working with the river.  Take a look at the following article: http://loosexaml.wordpress.com/2012/09/03/how-to-get-a-mongodb-oplog-without-a-full-replica-set/